# how to get the value of selected data in combo box?

Tags: java, vaadin

//this is my textfield

```
TextField quantityStock = new TextField("Available Stock");
```

//this is my combo box

```
ComboBox<Item> itemList = new ComboBox<>("Item");
```

//this is my code

```
public SoldItemForm(List<Item> allItems) {
        addClassName("item-form");

        // * item field 
        itemList.setItems(allItems);
        itemList.setItemLabelGenerator(Item::getItemName)
        itemList.addValueChangeListener(event->{
            if (event.getValue() != null){
                quantityStock.setValue(event.toString());
                
            }
        });
        

        // * Item Stock 
        quantityStock.setReadOnly(true);

        add(itemList, quantityStock);

    }
```

I want to display the selected item name in combo box to my textfield but
this line is diplaying:
*ComponentValueChangeEvent[source=com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox@5744eaab, value = com.smart.inventory.application.data.entities.Item@81, oldValue = null]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace event.toString() with event.getValue().getItemName(). Currently you are printing the whole event instead of the event's value/item.